# Given a System of Differential Equations, Show All Solutions in Phase Portrait are Elliptical

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

[image]

I found the eigenvalue,  $\lambda =i$

Then I did: det(A-$\lambda$)•(**V**) = $0$ where **V** = (x, y) is the eigenvector.

I Let x = 10, then solved for y:

y = 3 + i, therefore **V** $= (10, 3 + i)$

After separating the complex and real part of the solution the solution to the system is:

**Y**(t) $= k_1\left[10cos\left(t\right),\:3cos\left(t\right)-sin\left(t\right)\right]+k_2\left[10sin\left(t\right),\:cos\left(t\right)+3sin\left(t\right)\right]$

I know that up until this point, my answer is correct, and I understand it up to this point.

I do not understand how to show that all solutions on the phase portrait for this system are elliptical. How do I take the solution and form it in a way that proves this?

Help would be greatly appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Do you know how to change to new coordinates to bring the system to canonical form?

Comment: @HansLundmark I'm not too sure what you mean

Comment: Never mind, I just thought that you might have come across it in the course(?) that you're taking. Basically you take the real and imaginary parts of your complex eigenvector $\mathbf{V}$ as new basis vectors, and in that coordinate system it's much easier to see that you get ellipses. But if not, you're perhaps supposed to solve it some more direct way.

Answer (score 1):

As you already obtained

$$
x_1(t) = C_1\cos(t)+(10C_2-3C_1)\sin(t)\\
x_2(t) = C_2\cos(t)+(3C_2-C_1)\sin(t)
$$

or

$$
x_1(t) = a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)\\
x_2(t) = c\cos(t)+d\sin(t)
$$

solving for $\sin(t),\cos(t)$

$$
\sin(t) = \frac{c x_1-a x_2}{bc-ad}\\
\cos(t) = \frac{d x_1-b x_2}{a d-b c}
$$

and then

$$
\sin^2(t) + \cos^2(t) = 1 = \left(\frac{c x_1-a x_2}{bc-ad}\right)^2+\left(\frac{d x_1-b x_2}{a d-b c}\right)^2
$$

or

$$
(bc-ad)^2 = \left(c x_1-a x_2\right)^2+\left(d x_1-b x_2\right)^2
$$

which represent a general slanted ellipse.

NOTE

$$
b c-a d = C_1^2-6C_1C_2+10C_2^2 > 0 \ \ \mbox{for} \ \ C_1\ne 0,\ \ \mbox{and}\ \   C_2 \ne 0
$$

Attached the phase plane with an orbit associated to the initial conditions $x_1(0) = x_2(0) = 0.1$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient matrix is similar to $$J=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ You can find a suitable change of basis matrix $B$ by taking real and imaginary parts of one of the eigenvectors. In particular, we can take $$B=\begin{bmatrix}10&0\\3&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ to get the decomposition $BJB^{-1}$ for this system’s coefficient matrix.

The solutions curves of the original system are therefore affine images of the curves $$\exp(tJ)\mathbf C = \begin{bmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\\sin t&\cos t\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}.$$ Eliminating $t$ from the resulting parametric equations yields $x^2+y^2=c_1^2+c_2^2$, which is the equation of a circle, so the solution curves to the original system are ellipses.